# How to find matrix exponential using RootSum?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

From what I've been able to deduce, Mathematica uses a root sum scheme to determine the exponential of a matrix. Can someone please explain to me the theory behind this? I've searched, but have had no luck finding any literature on calculating a matrix exponential using root sums.

(Example: Help->RootSum->Applications->'Matrix exponential of any order:'

Comment: Per tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation#14568: "MatrixExp uses Putzer's method or Jordan decomposition."